# Setting a pagebreak based on row value in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report in Excel which generates a different amount of rows based on information in a record. I've set a hidden cell that prints the number of the last row, after which I would like the report to automatically set the page break, as currently I have to adjust it manually each time.

I've tried

```
Worksheets("TIC").HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Worksheets("TIC").Rows(125)
```

and

```
Worksheets("TIC").Cells(1, 7).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
```

Cell 1,7 is the one with 125 value, which obviously changes depending on row length.

Both of the examples above get executed but nothing changes in the report.

Is it possible to do that in Excel automatically through VBA or is it a function that simply not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a comment, that was strangely removed shortly after, that suggested using `.PageSetup.PrintArea`instead of `.PageBreak`
And the following code worked:

```
w = Cells(1, 7)
a = "$A$1:$G$" & w
Worksheets("TIC").PageSetup.PrintArea = a
```